# Angularjs + Ckeditor: Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ckeditor

I'm new to Angularjs and I'm currently try to use Ckeditor in my webapp.

I'm currently getting

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=editor&p1=Error%3A%…Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A390)

Any idea of what I did wrong?

In my Editor.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="editor">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Editor Test</title>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"</script>
    <script src="../bower_components/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"</script>
    <script src="../angular-ckeditor/angular-ckeditor.min.js"</script>

    <link href="../bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-select-1.11.2-dist/css/bootstrap-select.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="CkeditorController">
        <div ckeditor="options" ng-model="textdata" ready="onReady"></div>
        <br>  
        <div style="text-align: center">    
             note content: {{1+1}}   
            <button ng-click="getTextData() id="profile-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script scr="../angular/editor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my javascript: editor.js

```js
angular.module('editor', ['ckeditor'])
.controller('CkeditorController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.textdata = '';
  // you can set your configuration here 
  $scope.options = {
    language: 'en',
    allowedContent: true,
    entities: false
  };

  $scope.onReady = function () {
    //write you code here if you have to do something after editor is loaded    
  };

  // logging ckeditor textarea content in console
  $scope.getTextData = function() {
    console.log($scope.textdata);
  }
});
```

In my controller:main.js

```js
module.exports.index=function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hello world' });
};

module.exports.dashboard=function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('dashboard', {});
};

module.exports.editor=function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('editor', {});
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the **full URL** to that error report? Actually click it, then copy that URL. The truncated versions don't help anybody

Answer (score 2):

`></script>` is missing on your angular imports.

Comment: I think this may just be a typo in OP's question. Otherwise, the error message wouldn't say `localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js`

Comment: I added the </script> on my imports but it's still giving me the same error @Phil

Comment: <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"</script>

Comment: change to <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>